# MIDI - Force monophonic mode message (Enable voice stealing)

Tags: midi

Is there a universal MIDI message I can send to force the synthesizer into monophonic mode (enable voice stealing)?

In other words I would like to only allow one note to be played at any one time.  The latest note on will interrupt (steal) the voice from the last note on.

EDIT:

After some searching I think it must be something to do with the following Channel Commands

124 Omni Mode Off
125 Omni Mode On
126 Mono Operation
127 Poly Operation

I'll try those.

Answer (score 0):

I actually don't see any such CC in either the [original GM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_MIDI) or [GM2 specs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_MIDI_Level_2). Regardless, it's likely that such a CC isn't universally recognized by all synths.